# How to fire an activity at geofence transition?

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-geofence

I'm currently building my project on top of the geofencing tutorial found in the official documentation.

I would like to know the appropriate method of using geofence transitions to trigger something other than notifications with them (especifically, a class inside my own application that calls for a textview) and be closed on 'exit' (with no user interaction being mandatory). what's the simplest way to do this?

I am aware that the very documentation discourages the concept of geofence events triggering activities or fragments arguing that these elements are to be brought upon user action. My guess is that it pertains merely to using broadcast methods which have reach outside the current application. My aim is to set off the second class/activity only when the application is running on the foreground.

Thanks in advance for any help provided